# History of Tennessee vs Alabama in American football series

Tags: american-football, trivia, ranking

Has the University of Tennessee and the University of Alabama ever played American football against each other while being ranked #1 and #2 in the nation?

Comment: Are you writing about american football or football (=soccer)?

Comment: American football

Answer (score 4):

> Has the University of Tennessee and the University of Alabama ever played football against each other while being ranked 1 vs 2 in the nation?

No.

---

First, here are [the seasons](http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/tennessee/) in which the Tennessee Volunteers were at least ranked #2 during the season:

- 1938
- 1939
- 1951
- 1956
- 1967
- 1996
- 1998
- 1999
- 2001

Next, here are [the seasons](http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/alabama/) in which the Alabama Crimson Tide were at least ranked #2 during the season:

- 1937
- 1945
- 1961-1967
- 1971-1975
- 1977-1982
- 1986
- 1989
- 1992-1993
- 2008-2015

Thus, the only season both teams were ranked at least #2 is [1967](http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/alabama/1967-schedule.html). For this game that took place on October 21, 1967, Alabama was ranked 6th and Tennessee was ranked 7th. Tennessee won the game 24-13.

Comment: Before the AP rankings began, Alabama dealt Tennessee its only loss of the season [in 1930](http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/alabama/1930-schedule.html). Alabama finished 10-0 and Tennessee 9-1. The next year, Tennessee returned the favor and finished 9-0-1 to Alabama's 9-1. [Winsipedia](http://www.winsipedia.com/alabama/vs/tennessee) has a graphical visualization of each team's record over the years.